# CSS not changing when changing class name

Tags: javascript, css, html, media

I am working with the HTML5 media API and stuck at it's mute property. I have this mute button that i want to use to mute and unmute the audio for the particular video whenever i click it. The problem is that it works whenever i mute it but I cannot unmute it. The classes and title values get properly set to the appropriate values but there is no change in the volume or the icon image.   Here is a link to my jsfiddle code http://jsfiddle.net/7AS3C/1/  The CSS problem doesn't occur when i uploaded the code to jsfiddle. Would really appreciate  it if someone helped me out with  the javascript.

```
<div id="mediaplayer">
    <video id="media-video" controls>
        <source src='http://video.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm' type='video/webm' controls>
    </video>
    <div>
        <div id="media-controls">
            <progress id="progress-bar" min="0" max="100" value="0"></progress>
            <button id='replay-button' class='replay' title='replay' onclick='replayMedia();'>Replay</button>
            <button id='play-pause-button' class='play' title='play' onclick='togglePlayPause();'>Play</button>
            <button id='stop-button' class='stop' title='stop' onclick='stopPlayer();'>Stop</button>
            <button id='volume-inc-button' class='volume-plus' title='increase volume' onclick='changeVolume("+");'>Increase volume</button>
            <button id='volume-dec-button' class='volume-minus' title='decrease volume' onclick='changeVolume("-");'>Decrease volume</button>
            <button id='mute-btn' class='mute' title='mute' onclick='toggleMute();'>Mute</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the css

```
.unmute {
    width:45px;
    height:48px;
    background:url('mute.png');
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
.mute {
    width:45px;
    height:48px;
    background:url('unmute.png');
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
```

Here is my javascript

```
muteBtn = document.getElementById('mute-btn');

function toggleMute() {
    if (player.muted = false) {
        changeButtonType(muteBtn, 'mute');
        player.muted = "true";
    } else if (player.muted = true) {
        changeButtonType(muteBtn, 'unmute');
        player.muted = "false";

    } else player.muted = "false";
}

function changeButtonType(buttonType, value) {
    buttonType.title = value;
    buttonType.innerHTML = value;
    buttonType.className = value;
}
```

Comment: You're sure the classes are changing properly? Doesn't sound like it. Got a demo?

Comment: sorry, I have it on my computer. If someone doesn't have an answer, ill try and upload it to JSFiddle. Also, the class names are changed properly, i use the same function for changing the class names of other classes as well and they work just fine.

Comment: Do some logging (`console.log()`) to determine whether `changeButtonType()` is actually fired on both mute and unmute events.

Comment: I've done that mate. everything is fine there too. I used chrome to check whether the classnames and titles are set as well. They are actually set to the proper one.

Comment: I was passing the wrong string to the function..that was the problem. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conditional logic is assigning instead of comparing

```
if (player.muted = false) {
```

should be

```
if (player.muted === false) {
```

and

```
player.muted = "true";
```

should be

```
player.muted = true;
```

Same holds for the false block

Comment: how could i have missed that? That fixes the issue, thanks a lot. I guess i should take a better look at my code.

Comment: At the start you need to assign `player.muted = false` else player.muted will be undefined

Comment: its an easy mistake to make.. luckily .net warns you about some left handed operation